# how to use if else condition in tableView in Swift?

Tags: swift, tableview

[image: [enter image description here]]

In a tableViewCell I have many elements. And I get Status from an Api and if the status is "Dispatched", dispatched label should be ticked out.
I am uploading images so that you can understand it well.

```
if myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status == "Placed"{

    cell.placed.elementDesign(cornerRadius: 12, shadowRadius: 2, shadowOpacity: 0.5, offsetWidth: 2, offsetHeight: 2)
    cell.placed.text = "\(myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status) ✔︎"

}else if myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status == "Dispatched"{

    cell.dispatched.elementDesign(cornerRadius: 12, shadowRadius: 2, shadowOpacity: 0.5, offsetWidth: 2, offsetHeight: 2)
    cell.dispatched.text = "\(myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status) ✔︎"

}else if myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status == "Delivered"{

    cell.delivered.elementDesign(cornerRadius: 12, shadowRadius: 2, shadowOpacity: 0.5, offsetWidth: 2, offsetHeight: 2)
    cell.delivered.text = "\(myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status) ✔︎"

}else if myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status == "Payment Received"{

    cell.paymentReceived.elementDesign(cornerRadius: 12, shadowRadius: 2, shadowOpacity: 0.5, offsetWidth: 2, offsetHeight: 2)
    cell.paymentReceived.text = "\(myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status) ✔︎"

}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? Like what's not working with your code?

Comment: In placed, dispatched, delivered and payment received. Only one thing should be ticked in every cell. I my coding approach is wrong becouse it is reusable cell and after scrolling, Many elements are ticked out automatically.

Comment: Unrelated but it's pretty expensive to retrieve the value of `myOrderJSON[indexPath.row].status` 5 times in the worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom `UITableViewCell`, override **`prepareForReuse()`** method and reset the `text` of all `labels`, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    //rest of the code...

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        self.placed.text = nil
        self.dispatched.text = nil
        self.delivered.text = nil
        self.paymentReceived.text = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, perfectly working. I did -
        self.placed.text = "Placed"
        self.dispatched.text = "Dispatched"
        self.delivered.text = "Delivered"
        self.paymentReceived.text = "Peyment Received"